# one incident in each city

Tags: meaning, singular-vs-plural, numbers

a. Today we had gun-related incidents in Los Angeles, New York, Austin and Tampa.

b. Today we had a gun-related incident in Los Angeles, New York, Austin and Tampa.

c. Today we had a gun-related incident in Los Angeles, one in New York, one in Austin and one in Tampa.

Which can be used if we had one gun-related incident in each city?

I think (a) and (c) work, but (a) is unclear as to how many there were per city. I think it could still be used in this case.

Comment: In practice,  has there ever been a day, in recent history, in which there has not been multiple "gun related incidents" in New York?

Answer (score 1):

(a) is by far the most natural (except that it would probably be *there were* rather than *we had*, which sounds as though 'we' arranged the incidents on purpose). I think most readers would assume that there had been one incident in each city unless 'multiple' incidents were specified.

Answer (score 0):

As @KateBunting has mentioned, the most natural sentence is:

*Today there were gun-related incidents in Los Angeles, New York, Austin and Tampa.*

However, in the hypothetical situation that there was a single incident in each city and assuming a need to leave no room at all for error, consider using "each of":

*Today there was a gun-related incident in **each of** Los Angeles, New York, Austin and Tampa.*